# Perfect secrecy of affine cipher

Tags: substitution-cipher, affine-cipher

Given any probability distribution P r on the set
$\{k ∈ \mathbb{Z}_{26} : \gcd(k, 26) = 1\}$.
Show that the Affine Cipher achieves perfect secrecy if the key (k, a)
is used with probability $Pr(k) ·(1/26)$.

Answer (score 1):

An encryption scheme is said to achieve perfect secrecy if for **every probability distribution over *M*** (the messsage space), **every message** *m*$\in$*M* and **every ciphertext** *c*$\in$*C* for which Pr[*C = c*]>0:

Pr[*M = m | C = c*] = Pr[*M = m*] or, equivalently, Pr[E(*K,m*)=*c*]=Pr[E(*K,m'*)=*c*]   where *E* is the encryption algorithm that encrypt the message *M* according to the key *K*.
So I think you should define/identify also the probability distribution over the message space(*M*) before starting to talking about perfect secrecy. However, I think the AffineCipher cannot achieve perfect secrecy except in particular cases in which the probaiblity distributions are too much flat and the message to be enciphered very short.